# Edit chrome custom emulated device

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I recently created a few custom emulated devices on Google Chrome (Web Developer Tools).  After I added them I noticed that there doesn't appear to be a way to edit the properties I assigned to them.  I've searched and can't find the answer to how I can either edit or delete my custom created devices short of resetting the list to defaults.  Not sure what resetting will do but don't want to accidentally remove everything.  Anyone know how I can edit and delete my custom devices?

Comment: There's a pen icon when you hover the list in devtools => settings => devices.

Comment: Are you talking about the list where the "Add Custom Device" button is?  I hover and see no pen icon.  Or the drop down list of devices? Cause I don't see it there when I hover either.

Comment: devtools => settings => devices https://puu.sh/EB55P/be06288587.png

Comment: Odd.  For some reason I have neither the "pen" or the "trashcan" icons on my list.  https://adobe.ly/34zjPDX

Comment: Make devtools wider or switch to horizontal view.

Comment: That worked.  Thank you very much!